# Achartengine pie chart - labels rendered under the chart

Tags: android, achartengine

I use achartengine for displaying pie chart, but ran into some difficulties - sometimes labels are overlapping, and sometimes slices are rendered over labels and lines. Can I avoid this somehow?

[image]

Comment: try decreasing the text size for labels

Comment: I see way too many segments in your chart, how about removing them altogether and show Chart key with labels against each color on the top right of the pie chart.